# CSS pseudo-class vs. pseudo-selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, terminology

This is a bit of a pedantic question, but perhaps worth asking. Is there, mechanically, a difference between a pseudo-class and a pseudo-selector in CSS? We use the term interchangeably around here, but it seems that there's a reason for the two terms. Is there any use to differentiating the two?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [pseudo-class is a specified thing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-elements), while pseudo-selector is a made up word.

(Meanwhile, a pseudo-class matches an element when certain conditions are met (e.g. the mouse is pointing at it, or it is the first child of its parent), while a pseudo-element is something that can be matched but isn't a real or whole element, such as "Thing before an element" or "First line of text in an element".)

Answer (score 7):

*pseudo-selector* does make the odd appearance on the W3C site, but my initial search suggests that it is an old old term that has now been replaced with *pseudo-class*:

**pseudo-selector**

> the page pseudo-selector :first

http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/CR-css-print-20040225/#section-selectors

> CSS has a "lang" pseudo-selector that automatically uses the appropriate attribute depending on the media type

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/

**pseudo-class**

> 5.11.4 The language pseudo-class: :lang

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#lang

...and many more.

**Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes**

Then there's the descriptions for *pseudo-elements* and *pseudo-classes*:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements

So it looks to me as though pseudo-selectors are no longer in vogue...

Comment: I suppose *pseudo-selector* is a handy generic term for a selector which selects for *pseudo-classes* and *pseudo-elements*.  Just a thought (and a thought that is similar to Dan Heberden's comment about his own answer).

Comment: I'm late, but IMO it makes no sense to have a generic umbrella term for two completely unrelated things. It's a good thing they were careful to stop using the term "pseudo-selector"...

Answer (score 2):

a **pseudo-class** is the actual psuedo element, such as :hover, :active, etc..

a **pseudo-selector** is the complete selector that *contains/uses* a pseudo-class. such as a:hover, a:active

but [pseudo-class](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp) is what people *should* be saying/typing. pseudo-selector I think came from people knowing there was 'pseudo' and 'selectors' so 'why the hell not put them together?' kind of thing.

Comment: I'm not sure about this pseudo-selector concept... do you have any references? Because right now I'm more in favor of @david dorward's answer

Comment: I have references for pseudo-class because it's defined as the "active" or "hover". the term selector is just that, the selector. If I have `input[name=username]` - that is a _selector_ . No references, just common sense and logic :)

Comment: Your first sentence contradicts itself (a pseudo-class is not a pseudo-element). Your second sentence doesn't seem to match how people use the term "pseudo-selector", but in any case that term is unofficial, colloquial and just plain wrong, which is why there aren't references for it.

Comment: By the way, the [CSS3 selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax) calls things like `a:hover` and `a:active` "sequences of simple selectors", and the [CSS4 draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#structure) calls them "compound selectors". These are chains or groups of simple selectors that are not separated by any combinators. So we have some official terms to use, and that keeps pedants like me happy ;)

Comment: An important distinction from [the CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-elements): "**Pseudo-classes** are allowed anywhere in selectors while **pseudo-elements** may only be appended after the last simple selector of the selector." It helps me to distinguish the two by momentarily forgetting about "pseudo" and just thinking about the difference between a class and an element.